# sphinx, buildbot (and code coverage). how do they integrate?

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I have a not-so-small python package, with quite some history, documented with docstrings.  During its development we introduced [buildbot](http://trac.buildbot.net/) and later on [Jenkins/Hudson](http://jenkins-ci.org/).  Recently I added a [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) recipe to my `buildbot.cfg`, in order to collect the documentation from the sources and keep up to date web accessible docs.

so far, so good: each time I commit a change, Jenkins takes care of extensively checking the package, generating a very complete overview and updating our documentation site.

one of the sphinx extensions I enabled: [coverage](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/coverage.html), for documentation coverage report, which is currently undocumented.

I execute sphinx in my buildbot-generated environment, and 
I don't seem to manage to include the coverage statistics in the sphinx-generated documentation site!

any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated on the [sphinx.ext.coverage page](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/coverage.html), coverage is computed if one specifies the builder `-b coverage`.

the result is the file `"python.txt"`, a ReST file.  It is your task to integrate it in your own documentation.

Comment: Hi, tank you for the awnser but you link dosn't work anymore. Would this be the correct link? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/coverage.html